# Cross-Origin Request Blocked, header Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, go, fetch, go-iris

I was writing a blog application which has front end in react + typescript and backend in go iris. I'm doing a get request to fetch blog content. Backend runs at localhost:5000 and node at localhost:3000.But it fails with the error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/getposts. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I have already configured CORS in the backend

```
Cors := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins:   []string{"http://localhost:3000"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        AllowedMethods:   []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"},
        AllowedHeaders:   []string{"Cache-Control", "X-File-Name", "X-Requested-With", "X-File-Name", "Content-Type", "Authorization", "Set-Cookie", "Cookie"},
        Debug:            true,
    })
authConfig := basicauth.Config{
        Users:   map[string]string{USER_NAME: PASSWORD},
        Realm:   "Authorization Required", // defaults to "Authorization Required"
        Expires: time.Duration(30) * time.Minute,
    }

authentication := basicauth.New(authConfig)
app := iris.New()
app.Use(Cors)
app.Get("/getposts", authentication, GetPostsHandler)
```

This is how I send request

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000/getposts", {
  method: "get",
  credentials: "include",
  mode: "cors",
  headers: [
    ["Content-Type", "application/json"],
    ["Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("Sreyas:password")]
  ]
})
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      response.json().then(rawdata => {
        this.setState({ blogdata: rawdata });
      });
    } else {
      console.log("No posts");
      this.setState({ blogdata: null });
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Server Error");
    this.setState({ blogdata: null });
  });
```

I searched and tried for hours to fix this problem but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried `AllowedOrigins: []string{"*"},`, i.e. it will let all origins have access to the API?

Comment: @Tholle yes i have.It didn't work :(

Comment: Alright, that's frustrating. Have you tried removing `AllowedOrigins` entirely? [Looking at the source, it seems that would allow all origins as well](https://github.com/iris-contrib/middleware/blob/8b2080bf3bf80ce86666bdb629931b172f74544e/cors/cors.go#L93-L97).

Comment: @Tholle Still not working :(

Comment: Are you using create-react-app? Try adding `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` in your `package.json`, as [outlined here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development).

Comment: Yes i'm using create-react-app and adding proxy didn't work :(

Comment: I've personally found CORS to be pretty frustrating to solve. Have you considered running NGINX and routing your back-end and front-end to run on the same port (e.g. running your back-end on 5000, your front-end on 3000, and routing them through NGINX to both run on 4000)? This would let you leave all the CORS rules in place.

Comment: @Slotheroo Thanks a lot!!! I used ngnix to proxy and it worked charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Slotheroo for his suggestion to use nginx and that was the only possible way i could over come this problem.I used nginx to proxy the requests and route both front end and back end to 8000 port. I will leave a sample of my nginx server configuration and changes made to code here so that it helps anyone in future :)

*(Please note that using loop back ip like "localhost" can affect performance on loading and sending request therefore use exact ip of the machine to overcome such performance issue)*

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
        listen       8000;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
        location /getposts {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/getposts;
        }

    }
```

Added localhost:8000 to Allowed Orgins in backend

```
AllowedOrigins:   []string{"http://localhost:8000"},
```

request is now send to 8000 port

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/getposts',{
                    method: 'get',
                    credentials: "include",
                    mode: "cors",
                    headers: [
                        ["Content-Type", "application/json"], 
                        ["Authorization","Basic "+btoa('Sreyas:password')],
                    ]     
            }).then((response) => {
                if(response.ok){
                    response.json().then(rawdata =>{
                        this.setState({blogdata:rawdata})
                    })
                }else{
                    console.log("No posts")
                    this.setState({blogdata:null})
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("Server Error")
                this.setState({blogdata:null})
              })
    }
```